# Пакет Блога для Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите готовый пакет блога для интеграции в работающий проект.
Все что я видел до этого мешают работе основного проекта либо сложно управляются.

Если таких  пакетов нет возможно у вас есть идеи как сделать блог в короткие сроки с использованием посторонних пакетов.
Например уже думали над тем чтобы поднять блог по готовому пакету как отдельный апликейшен с доступом в админку а за данными просто ходить в другую базу но это какое-то извращение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как другие пакеты не давали нужного функционала из коробки был выбран canvas.toddaustin.io после нескольких часов танцов с бубном все завелось но пакет сорит своими файлами и перезаписывает своиже конфиги что дико мешает. Но что-то с этим придумаем)

Answer (score 5):

Вот учебный блог:

> https://github.com/vasilukwolf/LaravelLearnBlog

Есть варианты из композера:

> https://packagist.org/packages/didcode/laravel-blog

В качестве варианта можно отдельно сделать Wordpress быстро.
Но думаю вариант из композера интегрировать будет просто.
Главное используйте системы контроля версий правильно.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по топу скачивания:

1) [serverfireteam/blog](https://github.com/serverfireteam/blog)

2) [jcc/blog](https://github.com/jcc/blog)

3) [mb-programmer/startpoint](https://github.com/mb-programmer/startpoint)